# awk print 4 columns with different colours - from a declared variable

Tags: awk, colors, multiple-columns

I'm just after a little help pulling in a value from a variable. I'm writing a statement to print the contents of a file to a 4 columns output on screen, colouring the 3rd column depending on what the 4th columns value is.

The file has contents as follows...

```
 Col1=date(yymmdd)
 Col2=time(hhmmss)
 Col3=Jobname(test1, test2, test3, test4)
 Col4=Value(null, 0, 1, 2)
```

Column 4 should be a value of null, 0, 1 or 2 and this is the value that will determine the colour of the 3rd column. I'm declaring the colour codes in a variable at the top of the script as follows...

```
 declare -A colours
 colours["0"]="\033[0;31m"
 colours["1"]="\033[0;34m"
 colours["2"]="\033[0;32m"
```

(note I don't have a colour for a null value, I don't know how to code this yet but I'm wanting it to be red)

My code is as follows...

```
cat TestScript.txt | awk '{ printf "%20s %20s %20s %10s\n", "\033[1;31m"$1,"\033[1;32m"$2,${colours[$4]}$3,"\033[1;34m"$4}'
```

But I get a syntax error and can't for the life of me figure a way around it no matter what I do.

Thanks for any help

---

Amended code below to show working solution.

I've removed the variable set originally which was done in bash, added an inline variable into the awk line...

```
cat TestScript.txt | awk 'BEGIN {
                                colours[0]="\033[0;31m"
                                colours[1]="\033[0;34m"
                                colours[2]="\033[0;32m"
                                }
                                {printf "%20s %20s %20s %10s\n","\033[1;31m"$1,"\033[1;32m"$2,colours[$4]$3,"\033[1;34m"$4}'
}
```

Comment: Please, Are you declaring the array `colours` in `bash` and trying to use inside am `awk` program using `bash` syntax (`${colours[$4]}`)?

Comment: The array is declared in bash

Comment: Amended the code to include a working solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `colours` array in `awk`.

Either

```
BEGIN {
        colours[0]="\033[0;31m"
        colours[1]="\033[0;34m"
        colours[2]="\033[0;32m"
}
```

or

```
BEGIN { split("\033[0;31m \033[0;34m \033[0;32m", colours) }
```

But in the second way, remind the first index in the array is 1, not 0.

Then, in your `printf` sentence the use of `colours` array must be changed to:

```
,colours[$4]$3,
```

But if you have defined the array using the second method, then a `+1` is required:

```
,colours[$4+1]$3,
```

Best regards

Comment: Excellent, thank you, thats worked a treat. I've amended the code now and updated the example above. Any idea how I can change the null values into 0?

Comment: Please, explain what does that `null` value mean? Is it the string `null`? Is it the "empty" value?, i.e. the line has 3 columns, not 4?

Answer (score 0):

In [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you can use the built-in `ENVIRON` hash to access the environment variables.

So instead of `${colours[$4]}` (which syntax is for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) not for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)) you can write `ENVIRON["something"]`. Unfortunately arrays cannot accessed on this way. So instead of using `colours` array in environment you should use `colours_1`, ..., `colours_2`. and then you can use `ENVIRON["colours_"$4]`.